# Pygame keyboard input issue

Tags: python, keyboard, pygame

I am trying to get user keyboard input using pygame. However, the problem is that after I run my code on IDLE, the keyboard input is never read by the program, and whatever I type is shown on the shell. Same issue if I run my code on PyCharm. Any idea? Below is my code:

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
running = True
while running:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_w:
            print("Yup!")
     pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Why the hack are you running a `pygame` app in terminal?! `pygame` is for making games in non-terminal windows!

Comment: It did not work even if I ran using IDLE or pycharm...

Comment: Make sure the pygame window has the focus, otherwise your keyboard input will not be recognized!

Comment: It is focused when I run the code, but still same problem..Keyboard input is never read...

Comment: Do you get any error? It should be `pygame.KEYDOWN` and `pygame.K_w`... With this, it works fine for me on Windows 10 Python 3.4.4

Comment: No error at all. I'm working on Python3.5.1 on Mac.

Comment: If the above is the full code you use, you should get `NameError: name 'KEYDOWN' is not defined`, while it's not defined by you!

Comment: I had from pygame import * in my code, so it's okay to have KEYDOWN. What I'm saying is that, even if I changed to pygame.KEYDOWN, it did not return me any error, but keyboard was not responding still

Comment: I have no Mac so I cannot reproduce. Is the keyboard layout the right? And what about just testing for `elif event.type == KEYDOWN: print("Yup")`? Does this work?

Comment: It doesn't work because it can't detect any key pressed on my keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same issue, also on a Mac using Pycharm and python 3.6. I'm printing the events and only MouseMotion events are recorded, rather than KeyDown.

**Edit:** apparently it's a known issue: [Window does not get focus on OS X with Python 3](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/203/window-does-not-get-focus-on-os-x-with)

This is my code, and it also should work:

```
while not crashed:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    print(event)
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        crashed = True

    # get current list
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        print("UP")

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_1:
            print('this DOES work! :)')
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x_change = -5
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_change = 5
        elif pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            print("UP")
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_change = 0

    pygame.display.flip()

x += x_change

gameDisplay.fill(black)
ship(x, y)

pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly for me

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
windowSize = width,height = 800,600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(windowSize)


running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            quit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                print("Yup!")



    pygame.display.flip()
```